# Copy List and retain version history

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Hi I need to copy a list item to an archive list. In SPD I tried the 'Copy Item' action. this worked but I lose all versions.

I've tried http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/552a0d50-176b-41a6-bd7a-399713924359/ but it does not retain versions either.

Does anyone know of a way round this? Any custom actions out there?

Thanks

Comment: Does the list you are copying to have the same version settings? Can you write custom code (server)? There are several tools out there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this need to be automated?  Have you tried moving using *Site Content and Structure* from the Site Settings?  (Publishing needs to be turned on).

I just tested this out.

If you Copy using Site Content and Structure it will **NOT** retain version history.

If you Move using Site Content and Structure then it **WILL** retain version history.

Make sure **BOTH** lists have version history turned on and have the same exact columns.

Comment: hi
That has worked, great. I needed it automated, maybe via a workflow. How is this possible?